# not reading data from file in c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, class, oop, file-handling

I've written the following code but for some reason which i cannot figure, the code is not working or reading data from the file. I did place the file in the directory of the code but still it's not working. Please help me figure out what is wrong.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cstdlib>


using namespace std;

class author
{
public:
    string name;
    string email;
    string addr;

    friend class paper;
public:
    //author();
};

class paper
{
public:
    int id;
    string title;
    paper *ref[20];
    author a[8];


/*paper()
    {
        //ref[20]={};
    }*/
};

class reference
{
public:
    int pid;
    int refid[20];
};

int main()
{
paper *p[50];
fstream file;
file.open("data.txt",ios::in);

/*for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
{
if(!(file.eof()))
{
file.read((char*)p[i],sizeof(paper));
}
}*/


string s1,s2;
if(file)
{
    int i=0;
    while(!(file.eof()))
    {

        p[i]=new paper();

        getline(file,s1);
        p[i]->id = atoi(s1.c_str());
        getline(file,p[i]->title);

        //p[i]->ref = NULL;

        getline(file,s2);
        int k=atoi(s2.c_str());
        for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
        {
        getline(file,p[i]->a[j].name);
        getline(file,p[i]->a[j].email);
        getline(file,p[i]->a[j].addr);
        }

        for(int l=0;l<50;l++)
            {
                cout<<p[l]->id;
                cout<<p[l]->title;
                for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
                {
                    cout<<p[l]->a[j].name;
                    cout<<p[l]->a[j].email;
                    cout<<p[l]->a[j].addr;
                    cout<<"hello";
                }
            }
        i++;
    }

}
file.close();




/*  reference refobj[50];
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
{
    cin>>refobj[i].pid;
    for(int j=0;j<20;j++)
    {
        cin>>refobj[i].refid[j];
    }
}*/

ifstream fin;
fin.open("reference.txt");
reference refobj[50];
string s3,s4;
if(fin)
{
    while(!(fin.eof()))
    {
        for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
            {
                getline(fin,s3);
                refobj[i].pid= atoi(s3.c_str());
                for(int j=0;j<20;j++)
                {
                    getline(fin,s4);
                    refobj[i].refid[j]=atoi(s4.c_str());
                }
            }
    }
}
fin.close();



for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
{
    if(p[i]->id==refobj[i].pid)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<20;j++)
        {
            if(refobj[i].refid[j]!=0)
            {
                p[i]->ref[j]= p[j];
            }
        }
    }
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong ? what behavior do you expect ? what do you get ? What is the error ?

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] please when asking here. Also make sure you inspected your program with the debugger and stepped through.

Comment: The code does not display anything on the console. It does not even print a cout statement with a message.

Comment: I'm reading the contents from the file into the objects to create a database. All I'm asking is that the code is not opening the file and printing the contents. And yes I have inspected the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does not display anything on the console?

Weel... i'm not sure that it's the cause of this problem but... you never send a carriage-return to and you never flush the standard output.

Instead of

```
cout<<p[l]->id;
cout<<p[l]->title;
for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
 {
    cout<<p[l]->a[j].name;
    cout<<p[l]->a[j].email;
    cout<<p[l]->a[j].addr;
    cout<<"hello";
 }
```

try with

```
cout << p[l]->id << endl;
cout << p[l]->title << endl;
for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
 {
    cout << p[l]->a[j].name << endl;
    cout << p[l]->a[j].email << endl;
    cout << p[l]->a[j].addr << endl;
    cout << "hello" << endl;
 }
```

En passant, I suggest you other points to look carefully

--- Your way to use the `paper *p[50]` array is dangerous and I'm surprised that doesn't kill your program

You declare an array of unallocated pointers

```
paper *p[50]
```

then, in a cycle, you allocate one pointer every iteration

```
p[i]=new paper();
```

but you use all 50 pointer (allocated and not allocated) every iteration of the  cycle

```
for(int l=0;l<50;l++)
    {
    cout<<p[l]->id;
    cout<<p[l]->title;
    for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
        {
        cout<<p[l]->a[j].name;
        cout<<p[l]->a[j].email;
        cout<<p[l]->a[j].addr;
        cout<<"hello";
        }
    }
```

I suppose this should kill your program.

And I suppose that your intention was `cout` only the data of the single paper allocated iteration `i` (or how can you sure that the last value of `k` is valid for all 50 papers?) so simply

```
cout << p[i]->id << std::endl;
cout << p[i]->title << std::endl;
for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
    {
    cout << p[i]->a[j].name << endl;
    cout << p[i]->a[j].email << endl;
    cout << p[i]->a[j].addr << endl;
    cout << "hello" << endl;
    }
```

I strongly suggest you to avoid a direct use of dynamic allocation. You could simply use an array of 50 `paper` (not pointer to `paper`)

```
paper p[50];
```

or (IMHO, is better) using C++ containers; something like

```
std::vector<paper> p(50);
```

--- your way to load data from file is wrong; when you haver readed the last line, the `file.eof()` is still `false`; so, reading a file in a cycle checking against `!(file.eof())`, let you try another iteration, failing (but not testing) your reading. You should check every reading; something like [caution: code not tested]

```
// if p is an array (or a vector) of paper
for ( i = 0 ;    getline(file, s1) && getline(file, p[i].title)
              && getline(file, s2) ; ++i )
 {
   p[i].id = atoi(s1.c_str());

   int k = atoi(s2.c_str());

   cout << p[i].id << endl;
   cout << p[i].title << endl;

   for (int j = 0;    (j < k)
                   && getline(file, p[i].a[j].name)
           && getline(file, p[i].a[j].email)
           && getline(file, p[i].a[j].addr) ; ++j )
    {
      cout << p[i].a[j].name << endl;
      cout << p[i].a[j].email << endl;
      cout << p[i].a[j].addr << endl;
      cout << "hello" << endl;
    }
 }
```

--- Same problem reading "reference.txt"; avoid to check (only) `eof()`.

Comment: I did make the neccessary changes but still no output. The problem that I just realised is that my file is not opening at all.

Comment: The code did work!! Thanks alot. It was the EOF issue.